# Drupal 7 homepage tab issue

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am looking for help with an issue.  The drupal 7 site I am working on has a custom homepage.  When you go to homepage, on the browser tab, it initially shows the name of the site "NPE" but then it changes to "Homepage Title".  I've checked the metatags and everything seems to be right.  Does anyone have experience with this or other suggestions as to what could be causing this?

[image]
[image]
 [image]

Comment: Well, your `<title>` tag is outputting `Homepage Title`. Check your theme files as a start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drupal Homepage Title in Browser Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47207307/drupal-homepage-title-in-browser-tab)