# Drupal Homepage Title in Browser Tab

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am looking for help with an issue.  The drupal 7 site I am working on has a custom homepage.  When you go to homepage, on the browser tab, it initially shows the name of the site "NPE" but then it changes to "Homepage Title".  I've checked the metatags and everything seems to be right.  Does anyone have experience with this or other suggestions as to what could be causing this?

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have any javascript code that changes the title ?

Comment: I don't think so.  This is a site someone else created and I am trying to solve issues that were created.

Comment: Because when you are saying *"it initially shows the name of the site "NPE" but then it changes to "Homepage Title"* this can only be done through javascript, PHP can't do that, once you have the HTML response PHP's job is done!

Comment: Okay. I'll look to see if any javascript is running when it comes to that page in particular.  Thanks.

Comment: Try turning off javascript and see if the change occurs. That way you can find out whether it is javascript or not.